# Create an ASP.NET HTTP Module

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, ihttpmodule

Let us consider two class with same name space and extend IHttpHandler as below

**Class 1:**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace MyPipeLine
{
     public class clsMyHandler1 : IHttpHandler
     {
          public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
          {
               context.Response.Write("The page request is " + context.Request.RawUrl.ToString());
          }

     }

     public bool IsReusable
     {
          get
          {
               return true;
          }
     }
}
```

**Class 2:**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace MyPipeLine
{
     public class clsMyHandler2 : IHttpHandler
     {
          public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
          {
               context.Response.Write("The page request is " + context.Request.RawUrl.ToString());

          }

          public bool IsReusable
          {
               get
               {
                    return true;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

in above **namespace is: MyPipeLine which has two classes clsMyHandler1,clsMyHandler2** there by

i have given entry in web.config file as

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
         <add name="mymodule" type="MyPipeLine.clsMyHandler1,MyPipeLine.clsMyHandler2" />   
      </modules>        
</system.webServer>
```

and when i compiled the application it throw me error as

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyPipeLine.clsMyHandler2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I think C# see all modules like classes.  Do you have any idea for solving this question?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a module and implementing interface for HTTP Handler. Use this [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx)

Comment: i have created module but i need to start two classes at a time at each request

Comment: but in both classes you are implementing IHTTPHandler. The error you are getting is due to not implementing IHttpModule.

Comment: it goes like this public class clsMyHandler2 : IHttpModule

Comment: also for two requests at a time you need to create two separate modules and add separate entries in web.config